# TypeScript permits implicit lateral subclass cast? (yikes!)

Tags: typescript

I love TypeScript and have been using it for probably 7 years. However, I have just come across this issue and it seems to make TypeScript's typing system HORRIBLY broken. This is very strange because I have never noticed this before and I feel like I'm going crazy lol. Hopefully I am just missing some simple compiler flag or something!

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

let c: C = new B();
```

How can I make TypeScript *NOT* allow the assignment on the last line?

Thanks.

Comment: "*How can I make TypeScript NOT allow the assignment on the last line?*" have the classes be *in any way* different to each other. Other than name. The type system is, and always has been, structural. There is nothing different between the structure of A, B, and C.

Comment: Ok, good point. I will expand on the description to show why this is broken. It involves generics.

Comment: For reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, it does. It's very similar to what I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I can achieve what I want just by adding a private "discriminator" property, like this:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {
  #t: 'B' = 'B';
}
class C extends A {
  #t: 'C' = 'C';
}

let c: C = new B(); // NO LONGER ALLOWED!
```

Thanks to @VLAZ for giving me the idea!